# Ошибка сборки docker

Tags: docker

Запустил на сборку [свой докер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444766/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-docker#comment2579435_1444766). Ждал полчаса пока собирался docker и на 8 из 10 шаге вышла ошибка

```
#9 158.7 Collecting pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
#9 158.8   Downloading pytz_deprecation_shim-0.1.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
#9 159.1 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==301 (from versions: none)
#9 159.1 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==301
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
```

В чем может быть проблема? Это может быть из-за конфликта ОС?  Ведь, сборка на сколько я понимаю идет в Ubuntu, а я собираю через PowerShell.

Comment: В том, что докер это линукс, а в линуксе не бывает никакого win32. Ищите, откуда у вас взялся этот pywin32, и удаляйте из проекта

Comment: @andreymal, да проблему с **pywin32** решил после того как сформировал **requirements.txt** на проекте, который работал на Ubuntu. Но проблема все равно висит, говорит что доступен pip с новой версией, а у меня типа старый. Я пытался обновить через **RUN pip install --upgrade pip && python -m pip install -r requirements.txt** - но ничего не получилось...

Comment: А не пофиг ли?) Пусть будет старый, ничего страшного не случится

Comment: @andreymal, Ну если бы он не сборка образа не стопарилась - то было бы пофиг))

Comment: Предупреждения ни на что не влияют, если у вас стопарится сборка, то точно не от этого