# Правильная организация докера

Tags: docker

[Пытаюсь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444801/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-docker) создать докер-образ, но выходят ошибки. Соответственно я их потихоньку решаю, но этот процесс долгий. Я всегда пользуюсь такой командой для сборки:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml build
```

Назрел вопрос:
Обязательно ли всегда мне его собирать? Можно ли его сначала запустить и посмотреть - работает ли он? И если работает, то тогда уже собрать, а то ждешь по полчаса сборку и потом ошибка выпрыгивает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет нельзя, контейнеры запускаются из образов, поэтому его нужно сначала собрать.

Но вам никто не запрещает проверить ваши команды без сборки образа. Предположим вы ходите собрать образ на основе `alpine`.

Вы можете его запустить через `docker run` и внутри поэтапно выполнить все ваши команды: `apk add ...`, `make && make install` и т.д.

Также когда докер собирает образ, у него есть промежуточные слои (у них нет имен, а просто хеши, которые выводятся в консоль), их тоже можно запускать по отдельности, например, проект у вас собрался нормально, но потом при копирование не нашло какой-то путь, вы можете запустить промежуточный образ `docker run <hash>` и посмотреть, что внутри.